# Exception when subclassing Excel 2010 in .NET

Tags: excel, vsto, subclassing

I tried to subclass the main window of Excel 2010 from a VSTO add-in. This results in an exception and a crash of Excel when the program closes.

So I created a small example that reproduces the error on my machine. Obviously the call to CallWindowProc throws a ThreadAbortException when called for WM_CLOSE.

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

Private Const GWL_WNDPROC As Integer = -4

Private Delegate Function WndProcDelegate( _
    ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
    ByVal msg As Int32, _
    ByVal wParam As Int32, _
    ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong _
    Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
        ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
        ByVal nIndex As Int32, _
        ByVal dwNewLong As IntPtr) As Int32

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong _
    Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
        ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
        ByVal nIndex As Int32, _
        ByVal dwNewLong As WndProcDelegate) As IntPtr

Private Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" _
    (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As IntPtr, ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, _
     ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)> _
    Private mWndProc As WndProcDelegate

Private mPrevWindowProc As IntPtr

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    mWndProc = New WndProcDelegate(AddressOf SubWndProc)

    mPrevWindowProc = SetWindowLong(New IntPtr(Application.Hwnd), GWL_WNDPROC, mWndProc)
End Sub

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown
    SetWindowLong(New IntPtr(Application.Hwnd), GWL_WNDPROC, mPrevWindowProc)
End Sub

Private Function SubWndProc( _
        ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
        ByVal msg As Int32, _
        ByVal wParam As Int32, _
        ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32

    Try
        Return CallWindowProc(mPrevWindowProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Function

End Class
```

Is this just happening on my machine or am I doing something wrong?

BTW, it makes no difference if I restore the WndProc in the WM_CLOSE or WM_DESTROY event, Excel crashes all the same.

Excel 2010, Windows XP, VS 2008

Comment: Seems like there is no easy solution. At least I have found a workaround: On receiving WM_CLOSE restore the original WndProc, `PostMessage(WM_CLOSE)` (so it will be processed by WndProc) and return. Somewhat dodgy and it leaves the window unsubclassed if the users cancel the save changes dialog, but better than nothing.